# The largest Monday number

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

A Monday number is a positive integer $N$ with the following three properties:

- The decimal representation of $N$ does not contain the digit 0
- The decimal representation of $N$ does not contain any digit twice
- $N$ is divisible by every digit $D$ that occurs in its decimal representation

What is the largest Monday number?

Comment: Can you clarify rule 2 please? Should it state that N contains no more that one of any digit (otherwise digits can appear 3  or more times)?

Comment: Why Monday? You named it yourself, or is there such a mathematical concept?

Comment: My guess is that it is because today is Monday and perhaps he will give us a puzzle every day so tomorrow a puzzle with a Tuesday number might be asked

Comment: @GordonK - I think that's a given, because if a digit is allowed more than twice, there would pretty much be no limit, making it impossible to define a "largest" number with these properties. 987654321 would therefore be the largest potential candidate by rules 1 and 2.  (Though it fails rule 3.)

Comment: Because of rule 3, rule 1 doesn't make sense. Of course you can't have 0 if you have to be able to divide by each digit!

Comment: @corsiKa I would say rule 1 is redundant, not that it doesn't make sense

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase "The existence of rule 1 doesn't make sense"

Comment: I can see people questioning, "what about zero?!" if the first rule wasn't there.  Because divide by zero is undefined, they might think its somehow exempt from rule #3.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I assumed that that was precisely why it was mentioned specifically.

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59014

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Notice 9867312 is a Monday number.

The largest Monday number may not contain 5 because in this case it would end in 5, and thus not be divisible by 2, 4 and 8, so it would have at most 6 digits.

On the other hand, a Monday number may not have 8 digits. Indeed, if that were the case, the preceding paragrph would imply such a number has each digit but 0 and 5 in it. In particular, it would have the digit 3. But the sum of its digits would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 40, which is not divisible by 3.

It follows that the largest Monday number must have 7 digits. If it has the digits 9, 8 and 7 it must be a multiple of 504, and it's easy check the highest Monday number that is a multiple of 504 is 9867312. Because we know the largest Monday number has 7 digits, it follows that this is the largest such number.

Comment: As addition to the answer: We can know that if there is a 7 digit answer that the removed digit must be the digit 4. Because the sum of 98764321 = 40 and the sum of the digits must be divisible by 9 to be divisible by 9 and 4 is the only single digit number that can be removed from 40 to make a number divisible by 9,

Comment: That is correct, for 7 digit answers with the number 9 in them.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: and potential seven-digit answers *without* the number 9 in them are smaller than 9867312 :-) But anyway 9 and 5 can't be the missing digits because of divisibility by 3.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You meant 9 and 6, right?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: no, I meant that the 7-digit number in question cannot consist of the digits 1,2,3,4,6,7,8, that is to say the two missing digits cannot be "9 and 5". It's also true that the missing digits can't be "9 and 6", (since we already know that 5 *has* to be missing), and that they can't be "6 and 5" (because of divisibility by 3), I just wasn't saying that :-)

Comment: "If it has the digits 9, 8 and 7 it must be a multiple of 504, and it's easy check the highest Monday number that is a multiple of 504 is 9867312."   (And if it doesn't have all of the digits 9, 8 and 7, then it can be at most 9864321, which is less than 9867312.) Nice job!

Comment: @KritixiLithos It is divisible by 9. $9867312 = 9 \times 1096368$.